# How to set custom context path of deployed applications with tomee-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, apache-tomee, contextpath

when deploying versioned wars for integration tests how can I manipulate the contexts of those wars whos names are out of my control.

For instance:

```
<groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>

<configuration>
    <tomeeVersion>1.7.2</tomeeVersion>
    <path>/integration-adapter</path>
    <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
    <tomeeHttpPort>25180</tomeeHttpPort> 
    <systemVariables>
                <org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>debug</org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>
                <org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage>IntegrationTest</org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage> 
    </systemVariables>
    <webapps> 
        <webapp>**com.mycom.backend:some-war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**</webapp> 
    </webapps>
</configuration>
```

The issue I have is, the included war files are deployed with the version in the context eg. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/some-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/`

How do I rename this when deployed using the tomee plugin ?

eg. `http://127.0.0.1:8080/some-war/`

Just to reiterate, these wars are not the artifacts I am currently generating as part of my build.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by specifying your own (custom) context path. This can be achieved within the `<webapp>` tag via appending `...?name=some-webui` at the end of the string of the fully qualified `war` file name.

The resulting plugin configuration block would then be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <tomeeVersion>1.7.2</tomeeVersion>
        <path>/integration-adapter</path>
        <tomeeClassifier>plus</tomeeClassifier>
        <tomeeHttpPort>8080</tomeeHttpPort> 
        <systemVariables>
            <org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>debug</org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel>
            <org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage>IntegrationTest</org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage> 
        </systemVariables>
        <debugPort>5005</debugPort>
        <args>-Dfoo=bar</args>
        <webapps>
            <webapp>com.mycom.ws:some-war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT?name=some-webservices</webapp>    
            <webapp>com.mycom.webui:some-war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT?name=some-webui</webapp>    
        </webapps>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resulting URLs should then be:

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/some-webui
- http://127.0.0.1:8080/some-webservices

Additionally you could externalize the names/version information by using maven properties for that:

```
  ...
  <webapp>com.mycom.ws:${webservice.artifact.name}:${webservice.artifact.version}?name=some-webservices</webapp>
  ...
```

with the following properties section:

```
<properties>
    <webservice.artifact.name>${project.artifactId}</webservice.artifact.name>
    <webservice.artifact.version>${project.version}</webservice.artifact.version>
</properties>
```